# How to cast 'System.IntPtr' to 'float[]'?

Tags: c#, converters

How can I get a `float[]` for this `IntPtr` so I can operate on it?
Or please let me know any method can be operated.
(I've tried using Array, Marshaling but all doesn't operate.) 
Please see the following.

Any help would be appreciate!

```
IntPtr pt = IntPtr.Zero;
Camera.Memory.ToIntPtr(s32MemID, out pt);

MIL.MbufPut(MilImage, pt);
```

`> C:\Ctest\idsCS\idsCS\Form1.cs(100,35): error CS1503: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'float[]'`

Syntax for those methods

```
uEye.Memory.ToIntPtr(out System.IntPtr ptr)
**uEye.Memory.ToIntPtr**(int s32MemId, out System.IntPtr ptr)
```

Description
Returns a pointer to the image memory of the active/given image memory ID.

Parameter

```
s32MemId(Image memory ID)

ptr(Pointer to the image memory)
  void **MbufPut**(
  MIL_ID DestBufId,  //in  
const void *UserArrayPtr  //in  
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Marshal.Copy` (this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a53bd6cz(v=vs.80).aspx )

Comment: So, the only way to accomplish this is with a data copy?  The OP is unclear on this point.

Comment: @John Not (that I know) with a managed safe array, you need to copy it for that. You can use the pointer directly if you can use `unsafe` as long as the (in this case), `float` data structure is the same. Within an unsafe block, you can do `float *pointer = (float *)myIntPtr.ToPointer()`, and then use `pointer` as an unsafe "array" (`pointer[offset]`)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, I would use Span

```
IntPtr ptr = ... ;
Span<T> sp = new Span<T>((T*)ptr, ...);
```

But this still has some limitations. Take into account that Span is a read-only struct and can be allocated only on the stack.